# How does the anime adaptation relate to the other parts of the Joker Game franchise?

Tags: joker-game

The Spring 2016 anime *Joker Game* uses, to the best of my knowledge, the same premise as a set of novels by Koji Yanagi. There is also a 2015 live-action film that Wikipedia states is based on the novel, and a manga based on the anime.

How does the anime relate to the previous adaptations in the franchise (i.e. the novels and film)? In particular, to what extent does the content of the film differ from that of the anime?